# How to do random.choice in C

Tags: python, c

As a Python intermediate learner, I made an 8 ball in Python.
Now that I am starting on learning C, is there a way to simulate to the way `random.choice` can select a string from a list of strings , but in C ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest thing to a "list of strings" in C is an array of string pointers; and the only standard library function that produces random numbers is `rand()`, defined in `<stdlib.h>`.

A simple example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h> // needed for the usual srand() initialization

int main(void)
{
    const char *string_table[] = { // array of pointers to constant strings
        "alpha",
        "beta",
        "gamma",
        "delta",
        "epsilon"
    };
    int table_size = 5; // This must match the number of entries above

    srand(time(NULL)); // randomize the start value

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i)
    {
        const char *rand_string = string_table[rand() % table_size];
        printf("%2d. %s\n", i,  rand_string);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

That will generate and print ten random choices from an array of five strings.

The `string_table` variable is an array of `const char *` pointers.  You should always use a constant pointer to refer to a literal character string like `"alpha"`.  It keeps you from using that pointer in a context where the string contents might be changed.

The random numbers are what are called "pseudorandom"; statistically uncorrelated, but completely determined by a starting "seed" value.  Using the statement `srand(time(NULL))` takes the current time/date value (seconds since some starting date) and uses that as a seed that won't be repeated in any computer's lifetime.  But you will get exactly the same "random" numbers if you manage to run the program twice in the same second.  This is easy to do in a shell script, for example.  A higher-resolution timestamp would be nice, but there isn't anything useful in the C standard library.

The `rand()` function returns a non-negative  int value from 0 to some implementation-dependent maximum value.  The symbolic constant `RAND_MAX` has that value.  The expression `rand() % N` will return the remainder from dividing that value by N, which is a number from `0` to `N-1`.

Aconcagua has pointed out that this isn't ideal.  If N doesn't evenly divide `RAND_MAX`, then there will be a bias toward smaller numbers. It's okay for now, though, but plan to learn some other methods later if you do serious simulation or statistical work; and if you do get to that point, you probably won't use the built-in rand() function anyway.

Comment: 8 months later, and I more than understand all the code as well as logic here. Thanks for your answer, and yes, I now tend to use `/dev/urandom` or `rand_s()` instead when I need *proper* randomness, but `rand()` is fine enough to print random messages in toy programs , which is what I had asked this for.

Answer (score 3):

You can write a function if you know the size of your array and use `rand() % size` to get a random index from your array. Then return the value of `arr[randidx]`

Comment: `rand() % size` gives rather poor distribution. You get better results by `rand() * size / (RAND_MAX)` – depending on RAND_MAX and size you might possibly have to keep overflow in mind, though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess I need a few more months of self-learning C to reach the point where I can understand what your saying... Well, I began only a week ago... Anyways, thanks a lot, I'll revisit your answer when I know enough.

Comment: Yup, can confirm, I understad all of this clearly now :)